Angular: How to handle "Loader" & "child div with piechart of c3.js" in parent component when isLoading is received from child once api is subscribed
In the below code snippet, I am trying to handle the behaviour of a css loader, as soon as the data is fetched and isLoading is false the loader should stop and the desired pie chart from child component should get generated and rendered in parent component's html.

The Pie Chart is generated using c3.js. The problem is that, as the data is fetched isLoading is not changing to false and Loader remains loading and pie chart is not getting displayed.
When debugged the code isLoading = false was never hiding the loader and never showed the pie chart. Hence not sure what exactly is the issue.


I have a child component named un-member-chart.component.ts which has two functionalities:


In the method fetchUnMemberData() I am fetching data from an API countryService.getCountriesData() and sharing it to another method named generateChartData()

then generating a pie chart using c3.js once the data is fetched from the API


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CountryService } from '../services/country.service';
import { BehavioralChangesService } from '../services/behavioral-changes.service';
import * as c3 from 'c3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-un-member-chart',
  templateUrl: './un-member-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./un-member-chart.component.scss']
})
export class UnMemberChartComponent implements OnInit {
  unMemberCount = 0;
  nonUnMemberCount = 0;
  constructor(private countryService: CountryService, 
    private behavioralChangesService: BehavioralChangesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchUnMemberData();
  }

  fetchUnMemberData() {
    this.behavioralChangesService.setIsLoading(true);
    this.countryService.getCountriesData().subscribe(undata => {
      this.unMemberCount = undata.filter(country => country.unMember === true).length;
      this.nonUnMemberCount = undata.filter(country => country.unMember === false).length;
      
      this.behavioralChangesService.setIsLoading(false); // comment no. 1 for reference
      this.generateChartData(); // comment no. 2  for reference
    },
    error => {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      this.behavioralChangesService.setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }

  generateChartData(): void {
    const chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#UnPieChart',
      data: {
        columns: [
          ['UN Members', this.unMemberCount],
          ['non-UN Members', this.nonUnMemberCount],
        ],
        type: 'pie',
        colors: {
          'UN Members': '#9bc400',
          'non-UN Members': '#9080ff',
        },
      },
      title: {
        text: '% of UN Members in the World',
      }
    });
  }

}


un-member-chart.component.html
<div id="UnPieChart"></div>


Service file from where api is called (country.service.ts)


const allDataUrl = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all';
export class CountryService {
// to fetch all data of the World
  getCountriesData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(allDataUrl);
  }
}


another service file named behavioral-changes.service.ts to handle isLoading boolean value so that I can handle loader behaviour in my parent component named home.component.ts

import { ChangeDetectorRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BehavioralChangesService {
  private isLoadingSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public isLoading$ = this.isLoadingSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  setIsLoading(isLoading: boolean):void {
    this.isLoadingSubject.next(isLoading);
    this.cdr.detectChanges(); 
  }
}


And the parent component home.component.ts which handles the isLoading in ngOnInit() and tells UI if loader is loading or not.


import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { CountryService } from '../services/country.service';
import { BehavioralChangesService } from '../services/behavioral-changes.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  isSidebarOpen = true; // sidebar toggle initial
  isLoading:boolean = false;

  constructor(private SidebarToggleService: CountryService,
    private behavioralChangesService: BehavioralChangesService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.SidebarToggleService.isOpen$.subscribe(isOpen => {
      this.isSidebarOpen = isOpen;
    });

    // for loader behaviour
    this.behavioralChangesService.isLoading$.subscribe(isLoading => {
      this.isLoading = isLoading;
    })
  }

  getSidebarWidth() {
    return this.isSidebarOpen ? '250px' : '0'; // Set width based on open/close state
  }
  getFlexContainerMargin() {
    return this.isSidebarOpen ? '250px' : '0'; // Adjust margin based on sidebar state
  }

}




home.component.html where the child component will get rendered once the api fetches data successfully. And when data is not rendered a loader will be shown.

<div class="card">
    <div *ngIf="isLoading">
    <!-- Loader template -->
        <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Show <app-un-member-chart> when isLoading is false -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
        <app-un-member-chart></app-un-member-chart>
    </ng-container>
</div>

What I have tried I have tried using @Output and EventEmitter to emit boolean value of isLoading. But in this scenario also isLoading is never sent as false to parent html to show generated pie chart and stop showing loader.
`un-member-chart.component.ts
isLoading:boolean = true;
  @Output() isLoadingChange:EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
`

`fetchUnMemberData() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.emitIsLoadingState();
    this.countryService.getCountriesData().subscribe(undata => {
      this.unMemberCount = undata.filter(country => country.unMember === true).length;
      this.nonUnMemberCount = undata.filter(country => country.unMember === false).length;
      
      this.isLoading = false;    // 8
      this.emitIsLoadingState(); // 9
      this.generateChartData(); // 10
    },
  }

  emitIsLoadingState() {
    this.isLoadingChange.emit(this.isLoading);
  }

home.component.html
<div class="card">
<div *ngIf="isLoading">
<!-- Loader template -->
<div class="loadImage"></div>
</div>
<ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
<!-- Show <app-un-member-chart> when isLoading is false -->
<app-un-member-chart (isLoadingChange)="handleIsLoadingState($event)"></app-un-member-chart>
</ng-container>
</div>

What I expect: As soon as the data is fetched from the API, the loader should stop and the desired pie chart from child component should get generated and rendered in parent component's html instead of the loader.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Could you maybe share a StackBlitz where you managed to reproduce the error ?
